# unable to load datepick in Spring MVC Jquery

Tags: java, jsp, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

I want to implement the Datepick in my sample application form, i have done all the changes but still my page is not  able to load Datepick what mistake iam doing please let me know. ?

here is the Snapshot of my [image: Project class and binaries]

here is my web.xml

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
        <style>
    .error {
        color: red; font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>Add Employee Data</h2>

        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/files/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/files/jquery.js"></script>
         <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/files/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<script> type="text/javascript">       
  $(function() { 
  //Datepicker
  $('input[name=Dategiven]').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
   });
</script>       

        <form:form method="POST" action="/SpringHibernate/save.html">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="id">Employee ID:      </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="id" value="${employee.id}" readonly="true"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">Employee Name:      </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name" value="${employee.name}" placeholder="Name"/></td>
                    <td align="left"><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="age">Employee Age:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="age" value="${employee.age}" placeholder="Age"/></td>
                     <td align="left"><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="salary">Employee Salary:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="salary" value="${employee.salary}" placeholder="Salary"/></td>
                     <td align="left"><form:errors path="salary" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="address">Employee Address:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="address" value="${employee.address}" placeholder="address"/></td>
                     <td align="left"><form:errors path="address" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="Dategiven">Employee Date:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="Dategiven" value="${employee.dategiven}" placeholder="YYYY-MM-dd"/></td>
                    <td align="left"><form:errors path="Dategiven" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table> 
        </form:form>

  <c:if test="${!empty employees}">
        <h2>List Employees</h2>
    <table align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Age</th>
            <th>Employee Salary</th>
            <th>Employee Address</th>
            <th>Employee dategiven</th>
            <th>Actions on Row</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.age}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.address}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.dategiven}"/></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?id=${employee.id}">Edit</a> | <a href="delete.html?id=${employee.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

SpringHibernate-servlet.xml configuration for this

and also for this line `<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/files/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">`  iam getting Warning as

**Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - WebContent/WEB-INF/views/<%=request.getContextPath()%>/files/jquery-ui.css not found.**

can some one please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Keep the js & css files outside the WEB-INF folder**

Container doesn't allow direct access to the resources under WEB-INF folder. Place the resources i;e js, css, images under WebContent folder.

Also, the ideal way of computing the contextpath in a jsp is

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/templates/js/main.js"></script>
```

Open the browser console, check all the errors, check the request url for the css & try hitting it on a new tab. If the resource is unavailable then the issue is with the url mapped for the resource in the jsp. Recheck the url.